# PHP Embedded JavaScript - ES6 Backticks - Do they work when nested?

Tags: javascript, php, ecmascript-6

I've looked around for an answer to this, but I haven't come across anything that works.

I have a button on a PHP page that fires a JavaScript function that fetches JSON from an API. It then loops through the entries and created a bunch of elements. The code I have thus far works, in that it returns the JSON data from the API and there are no errors. But it doesn't display the result.

My suspicion is that the embedded JS and use of ES6 template strings isn't working. Here is my code:

```
    <?php
  // Testing JavaScript. Might be a bit hack-ish. Never used PHP with API's.
  echo "<script>
  document.getElementById('getAPI').addEventListener('click', getAPI);
  function getAPI() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      let output = '<h2>API Result:</h2>';
      data.forEach(function(user) {
        output += `
          <div>
            <h3>${user.title}</h3>
            <p>${user.body}</li>
          </div>
        `;
      });
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
    })
  }
  </script>";
?>
```

Can anyone see anything obvious? I'm not entirely sure this is an efficient way of achieving this.

Comment: I'm not instantly sure why it isn't working, but can you not view the source of the page and see what Javascript is actually getting rendered? Also, `echo`ing a long literal string is (imo) stupid - just close the php tag, write whatever html you normally would on the page (where you don't need outer quote marks), then open a new PHP tag if needed.

Comment: What Robin said especially the part about dropping out of PHP to render the JS code.

Comment: It is unclear to me how the actual and the desired output differ from each other.

Comment: You need to show the resulting html, if you are asking why doesn't this echo work, at least show what it produces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't in the backtick operator, but in the fact you're using `$` symbol inside double quoted string. PHP will try to evaluate that to a variable, so your Javascript ends up rendered as:

```
output += `
          <div>
            <h3></h3>
            <p></p>
          </div>
        `;
```

If you really **must** have the PHP echo out the Javascript, then you'll need to escape the `$` sign, like so:

```
output += `
          <div>
            <h3>\${user.title}</h3>
            <p>\${user.body}</li>
          </div>
        `;
```

But like Robin pointed out in the comment to your question, you'd be better off to just separate the PHP from Javascript.

For example:

```
<?php
  // Testing JavaScript. Might be a bit hack-ish. Never used PHP with API's.
  // ... other PHP code
?>
  <script>
  document.getElementById('getAPI').addEventListener('click', getAPI);
  function getAPI() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {

      let output = '<h2>API Result:</h2>';
      data.forEach(function(user) {
        output += `
          <div>
           <h3>${user.title}</h3>
           <p>${user.body}</p>
          </div>
        `;
      });

      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
    })
  }
  </script>

<?php
 // ... more PHP code

?>
```

Last thing - you have `<p></li>` invalid HTML.